# Using GMF 2d extension classes in GEF

Tags: eclipse-gef, eclipse-gmf

I am trying to use the PolylineConnectionEx as my connector in GEF. Does anyone have experience doing this? I have tried to do it but it crashes our editor. I would like to use the PolylineConnectionEx because it has many "built in" features which I would like to use like the jump connector and the curved connections.